# Offsetting UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, ios6, uirefreshcontrol

I am currently using a JASidePanel for my application and I have a UITableViewcontroller with a UIRefreshControl as one of the ViewControllers for it. The width of my tableview still has a width of 320 pixels so the UIRefreshControl gets centered right in the middle of the view. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to offset the UIRefreshControl (moving the x by 20 pixels to the left) so that it looks centered when I have my side panel visible.

Thanks!
[image: JASidePanel]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change the frame of the table view?

Comment: Its coz I have alternating colored rows so if someone tries to look below the side panel, it looks incomplete :(

Comment: You can try adding a translation transform to the refresh control with an 'x' movement equal to the width of your side panel.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. Not sure if it'll work but I'll tryi t.

Comment: hello @user754905 have you tried below answers

Comment: Your thing works. I'm just testing a few things (since this solution is a bit hacky.) and will reward the bounty when I can which is 18 hours if everything goes well :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to set the frame of the `UIRefreshControl`. Use this code

```
UIRefreshControl *refContr=[[UIRefreshControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[refContr setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[refContr setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

[stocktable addSubview:refContr];
[refContr setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin)];

[[refContr.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 20, 30)];


NSLog(@"subViews %@",refContr.subviews);
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Awesome tip. Though FYI for iOS 7 it's 10 points less (i.e. to the left). So: [[refContr.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 20, 30)];

Comment: UIRefreshControl is not meant to be added as a subview... in my experience, doing so did cause crashes when the target was not removed... UIRefreshControl may cause other issues as well when added as a subview

Comment: Changing the frame of the first UIRefreshControl subview does the trick.

I'm using SWRevealViewController and that works:

`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGFloat rearPanelWidth = self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth;
    UIView *refreshView = self.refreshControl.subviews[0];
    CGRect refreshFrame = refreshView.frame;
    refreshFrame.size.width = rearPanelWidth;
    refreshView.frame = refreshFrame;
}`

Answer (score 72):

Try editing the `bounds`. For example, to move the control down +50px:

```
refreshControl.bounds = CGRectMake(refreshControl.bounds.origin.x,
                                   -50,
                                   refreshControl.bounds.size.width,
                                   refreshControl.bounds.size.height);
[refreshControl beginRefreshing];
[refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

Comment: This is a quicker and simpler solution than the accepted answer, but I'd take the accepted answer if I'd want my `UIRefreshControl` a bit more customized. I am personally using this solution.

Comment: can someone explain why setting -50 to y origin moves it down by 50 points?

Comment: Luke: origin 0,0 at bottom left.. the smaller the number, the lower the position.

Comment: You may also use `refreshControl.bounds =  CGRectOffset(refreshControl.bounds, 0, 50)`

Comment: For me, it is 50 not -50.

Comment: Why on earth is y-axis inverted for this one thing. Spent 45 minutes trying to position before this post saved my day. All of iOS UIKit is increase y to move down, and this one is decrease y to move down... what a pain.

Answer (score 15):

I needed to do this in order to move the UIRefreshControl downwards. My solution was to subclass UIRefreshControl, and overwrite the layoutSubviews method to set a CAAffineTransform translation on each subview. Unfortunately you can't just set a transform on the UIRefreshControl.

Change xOffset and yOffset as necessary.

```
@interface MyUIRefreshControl : UIRefreshControl
@end

@implementation MyUIRefreshControl

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xOffset, yOffset);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. I also like this better because you can parameterize the offsets with an init method.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 5:**

There are a couple of ways to change UIRefreshControl position. The setup of the refresh control is done with the most convenient way.

Example where the refresh control is part of the scroll view:

```swift
let refresher = UIRefreshControl()
refresher.addTarget... // Add a proper target.
scrollView.refreshControl = refresher
```

Please note that you can use tableView instead of the scrollView.

*Option 1:* You can play with the frame/bounds of the view.

```swift
scrollView.refreshControl?.refreshControl.bounds.origin.x = 50
```

*Option 2:* Or you can do it using Auto Layout.

```swift
scrollView.refreshControl?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

scrollView.refreshControl?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.refreshControl?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 3):

`UIRefreshControl`'s frame is automatically managed so trying to change it's position will likely yield in unexpected results (especially between iOS SDK versions). As you've noted, the control is always centered horizontally in it's superview's frame. Knowing this you can 'take advantage' of the situation by offsetting your superview.

In your case, set your table view's frame to `CGRect(-40, 0, 360, superViewHight)`. This will cause your table view to sit 40 points to the left of the window. So you will need to adjust your table view's content accordingly so that it sits 40 points to the right or just extends an extra 40 points, but the stuff rendering off screen should be padding.

Once you do this your `UIRefreshControl` will sit 20 points to the left as you desire due to the fact that it is centered.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, unfortunately I can't move the table because I have alternating colored rows and it makes this look ugly when the user looks under the sidepanel.

Comment: Not sure I understand why a horizontal shift would affect alternating rows that are laid out vertically?

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't read the answer correctly. This could work, but the subviews are gonna be a pain to get right.

Comment: Chris, would it make sense to create an invisible subview (of your superview that currently contains the refreshcontrol), then add the refresh control to that)?  This would provide a view which could be manipulated, without complicating layout of existing stuff. [I stumbled across this answer and don't actually have this situation, so not certain I've thought this through.]

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.2 solution is

```
let offset = -50

let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.bounds = CGRect(x: refreshControl.bounds.origin.x, y: offset,
                               width: refreshControl.bounds.size.width,
                               height: refreshControl.bounds.size.height)
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(networking), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
self.profileTable.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
    if (!_refreshControl)
    {
        _refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
        _refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

> _refreshControl.bounds = CGRectInset(_refreshControl.bounds, 0.0, 10.0); *// let it down with inset 10.0*

```
        [_refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(pullToRefresh)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
    return _refreshControl;
}
```

Comment: [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing]; put it in viewWillAppear to begin animation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift version similar to the workaround that Werewolf suggested. I'm using my own custom activity view class (`MyCustomActivityIndicatorView`) and it's also a subview of the refresh control, so I make sure I don't mess with it's frame, just the frame of the default subviews. After calling `layoutSubviews` on super I adjust the custom activity view's frame to match. This is all contained in a custom `UIRefreshControl` subclass.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {

    for view in subviews {
        if view is MyCustomActivityIndicatorView {
            continue
        } else {
            // UIRefreshControl sizes itself based on the size of it's subviews. Since you can't remove the default refresh indicator, we modify it's frame to match our activity indicator before calling layoutSubviews on super
            var subFrame = view.frame
            subFrame.size = activityView.intrinsicContentSize()

            // add some margins
            subFrame.offsetInPlace(dx: -layoutMargins.left, dy: -layoutMargins.top)
            subFrame.insetInPlace(dx: -(layoutMargins.left+layoutMargins.right), dy: -(layoutMargins.top+layoutMargins.bottom))

            view.frame = subFrame.integral
        }
    }

    super.layoutSubviews()

    activityView.frame = bounds
}
```

Note: I'm adding in UIView's layout margins in which isn't strictly necessary but gives my activity indicator some space to breath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass UIScrollView, following code will adjust UIRefreshControl location based on contentInset (works only for vertical scrolling but easily adoptable for horizontal)

```
override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    guard let refreshControl = self.refreshControl else { return }

    var newFrame = refreshControl.frame

    if contentInset.top > .zero {
        let yOffset = abs(contentInset.top + contentOffset.y)

        newFrame.origin.y = -contentInset.top - yOffset
        newFrame.size.height = yOffset
    }

    guard newFrame != refreshControl.frame else { return }
    refreshControl.frame = newFrame
}
```