# Positioning UIRefreshControl in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to change the content inset of the table view embedded in a table view controller. This controller contains a UIRefreshControl.

This is how I set the content inset in the subclass of table view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.contentInset = self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(80, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I suppose that the refresh control will be automatically update its frame according to the inset.
It works great in iOS 7. The refresh control will be dropped down according to the inset:
[image]

But in iOS 6. It seems that it will always stay on top and ignore the content inset:
[image]

Does anyone experience this before? I hope the refresh control in iOS 6 can update its frame according to the content inset. Thanks!!

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309268/offsetting-uirefreshcontrol