# Change the initial position of UIRefreshControl indicator in iOS App

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am developing iOS App with UITableView and UIRefreshControl.

I would like to change the initial position of UIRefreshControl indicator by 50px down from default. I write down the following code.

However, the initial position is not changed. it remains in its original position.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

```
CGFloat customRefreshControlHeight = 50.0f;
CGFloat customRefreshControlWidth = 320.0f;
CGRect customRefreshControlFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                              customRefreshControlHeight,
                                              customRefreshControlWidth,
                                              customRefreshControlHeight);
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] initWithFrame:customRefreshControlFrame];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(onRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Comment: I think you can find a proper answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59489992/6869609

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to subclass `UIRefreshControl` and override frame property. The following code works in all the cases I tested. You can also implement it without frame override by applying transform. Setting frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` doesn't work since iOS 11.

```
class OffsetableRefreshControl: UIRefreshControl {

  var offset: CGFloat = 64
  override var frame: CGRect {
    set {
      var rect = newValue
      rect.origin.y += offset
      super.frame = rect
    }
    get {
      return super.frame
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This works great for refresh control in `UICollectionView`! Thanks

Comment: this isnt working... where to add this code?

Answer (score 6):

Setting the frame directly doesn't work, but you can still use AutoLayout to put your refreshControl whenever you want. Just don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`.

For example, this code sets the refreshControl in the middle of the screen.

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
refreshControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint(item: refreshControl, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: refreshControl, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: This is no longer working

Answer (score 1):

Just simple (Swift)

```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        refreshController.frame = CGRectMake(refreshController.bounds.origin.x,
                                              50.0,
                                              refreshController.bounds.size.width,
                                              refreshController.bounds.size.height);
        refreshController.superview?.sendSubviewToBack(refreshController) // for fix overlap tableview
    }
```